# Post an image *after* post footer?

Tags: html, blogs, blogger

Question :

I know there are tutorials out there for creating post divider (an image) in between text posts, and i'm doing that too, EXCEPT

I want the image to be AFTER the post footer. Is this possible? My problem right now is, the image is showing in between the footer borders, and I want it to be AFTER the shadow (i.e after the bottom footer).

Help! I feel like the answer is so close yet i can't seem to figure it out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

user `<br />` after photo then the text will start from buttom of picture. if you want css solution, it's called `float: left;`

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid you misunderstand, I'm not editing a text post, I'm editing the post-footer. I posted an image after this code <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-3'/> but the image is showing up BEFORE the bottom-border of the post-footer (i.e between border-top: AND
border-bottom:) i'd like it to show up after border-bottom but idk how

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with a margin?
Try adding margin-top to the image. I think this may help.
Otherwise you could work with position: relative and add a top value.